# Value of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{{-x}^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$ The value of:
       $$\iint_{-\infty}^\infty e^{{{-(x}^2}+xy+{{y}^2)}}dxdy$$ is
A) $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{3}}$   B)$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$  C)$\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{3}}$  D)$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3}$

*Both the limits of double integral is from $-\infty$  to  $\infty$ *

I tried with integration by parts and it is leading nowhere.Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384732/find-the-value-of-int-infty-infty-int-infty-inftye-x2xyy2?noredirect=1&lq=1 You can see this link!

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2106239/44121