# Solve $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem in evaluating  the double integral $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}dxdy$$

I tried to use polar coordinates

$e^{-(r^2(5-8\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta))}$  but still unsolvable

Any help please

Comment: Complete the square in the numerator.  This will suggest a change of variables (a rotation) to use.

Comment: Use [this old answered question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106224/integral-of-a-two-variable-function-e-5x2-6xy5y2) to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I try to use a substitution x =u+v and y = u-v and works Like the old answered question using change of variables .

Comment: I try to complete the square but still unsolvable to me , but with the previous substitution it works .

Answer (score 15):

Assume that $Q(x,y)=Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2$ is a positive-definite quadratic form ($B^2<4AC$ and $A,C>0$) associated to the matrix $M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} A & B/2 \\ B/2 & C\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. By the spectral theorem $M$ is conjugated to a diagonal matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ via an isometry, such that

$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp(-Q(x,y))\,dx\,dy = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(-\lambda_1 x^2-\lambda_2 y^2\right)\,dx\,dy $$
equals, via Fubini's theorem, $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\lambda_1\lambda_2}}$. On the other hand $\lambda_1\lambda_2 = \det(M) = AC-\frac{B^2}{4}$, so
$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp(-Q(x,y))\,dx\,dy = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}. $$
In your case $B=-8$ and $A=C=5$, so
$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}\,dx\,dy = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{100-64}} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{3}}.$$

Comment: Hi Jack.  Happy New Year.

Comment: Thanks Jack . Can you tell me which branch of mathematics can i found this kind of solutions ? your solution seems great but i need to learn the mathematics of this solution

Comment: @OmranKing: you just need the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) and [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), plus the fact that $\det(M)=\det(A^{-1} M A)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot jack for helping me to understand the mathematics of it , i will read about your mentioned topics .

Answer (score 11):

Note that
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}dxdy
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{-\frac12(x+y)^2-\frac92(x-y)^2}dxdy
$$

and let $u=\frac1{\sqrt2}(x+y)$, $v=\frac3{\sqrt2}(x-y)$ to obtain

$$I = \frac13\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{-v^2}dv = \frac{(\sqrt\pi )^2}3 = \frac\pi3 $$

where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}du={\sqrt\pi}$ is used.

Answer (score 7):

> **Since the OP tried evaluating the double integral by transforming to polar coordinates, I thought that it would be instructive to show that the we can indeed proceed by the proposed polar coordinate transformation.**

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-5x^2-5y^2+8xy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-(5-8\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi))\rho^2}\,\rho\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{5-4\sin(2\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{5-4\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\tag1\\\\
&=\frac\pi3\tag2
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ one can use either the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) or [contour integration in the complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_3a_%E2%80%93_trigonometric_integrals,_the_general_procedure).

Comment: Thanks a lot . it's seems good to me . But I wondering about the integral 1/(5-4sin2x) how can we solve it ?

Comment: @OmranKing I suggested two ways in the post.  The first uses the tangent half-angle substitution $\sin(\phi)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, with $d\phi=\frac{2}{1+x^2}\,dx$; I provided a link to a reference.  The second uses contour integration; I provided an reference here also.

Comment: i wonder also about how we convert sin2x to sin x ? before equation (1)

Comment: @OmranKing That is a simple substitution of variable (Let $2\phi=x$) followed by exploiting the $2\pi$-periodicity of the sine function to note that the value of the  integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ is equal to the value from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$.