# To evaluate double integral over entire xy-plane

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, change-of-variable

The problem is to evaluate:

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(19x^2+19y^2+2xy)} \,dx\,dy$

Can anybody help me to solve this type problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $e^{a + b} \neq e^a + e^b$

Comment: oh yeah.. I am sorry..

Comment: There is a formula in my book hope it will help $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1/2(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^{2}}}{\sigma(\sqrt 2\pi)}=1$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501943/solve-int-limits-infty-infty-int-limits-infty-inftye-5x2-5y2/3502067#3502067

Comment: yeah.. got it.. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$19(x^2+y^2)+2xy=\frac{19}{2}[(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2]+\frac{1}{2}[(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2]$$ The the give double integral is
$$I=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-10u^2} e^{-9v^2} du ~ dv =\frac{4}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-10u^2} du \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-9v^2} dv= 2 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{40}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{6} =\frac{ \pi}{6\sqrt{10}}. $$

Comment: Thank you so much. But I guess it is 1/2 instead of 2 while changing the variables x,y to u,v.

Comment: But isnt it true that while changing variables we need to take the absolute value of reciprocal of the Jacobian? If so, then in your case, we have the Jacobian to be 2, therefore we have to take 1/2.

Comment: @MB17, Oh! yes, you are right, I have corrected i\t now.

Answer (score 2):

Since $Q(x,y)=19x^2+2xy+19y^2$ is a positive definite quadratic form [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3502030/44121)
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp(-Q(x,y))\,dx\,dy = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{19^2-1}}.$$